# AngularJS viewContentLoaded not executing on page refresh and initial load while using directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I am experiencing some inconsistencies when using a custom directive and relying on the viewContentLoaded event to run...

Below is a "bare-bones" version of the problem:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('someDirective', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {},
     controller: 'MyCtrl',
     templateUrl: 'my-template.html'
});


myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      alert('Consumed viewContentLoaded...');
  }
}]);
```

The event viewContentLoaded get's triggered on page refresh and initial page load when 
used like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-include="my-template.html"></div>
```

However, it doesn't get triggered on page refresh or initial page load when used as a 
directive:

```
<some-directive></some-directive>
```

Any ideas why the inconsistent behavior?

Comment: are you applying this directive to a template loaded by ngView?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is related to an open bug:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1213

There is really no work around this.

The proposed workaround:

```
myApp.run(['$route', angular.noop]);
```

fails for me with the latest AngularJs(1.2.10), with some sort of an "Injector error".